# Parse GET response

Tags: arduino

I am not able to extract the data I need from the GET response
I'd like to memorize only charcaters that comes between "-" and "-" because I don't need anything else. I tried using a while loop as shown below but it won't work

thank you

```
    String readString;

    while (client.connected() || client.available()) {
      char c = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer

      while(c != "-"); //this throw error
      readString += c; //places captured byte in readString
    }

    client.stop(); //stop client

    Serial.print(readString);

    String res = readString.substring("-","-"); //throw error
    String val = "happy";

    if(res == val){
      Serial.print(res);
      Serial.println(" happy");
    }else{
      Serial.print(res);
      Serial.println(" sad");
    }

  Serial.println("==================");
  Serial.println();
  readString=""; //clear readString variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here you have different problems.

1. You can't compare a char (`c`) and a string (`"-"`). You should use `'-'` to compare with a char.
2. That while in your loop will block the program execution. You should use a sort of state machine (using for instance a state variable).
3. There is no need for using a `substring` function if you properly write your reading function. In any case, the `substring` function wants the INDICES, not the chars.

This said, this code should work for your case:

```
// state =
// 0 -> waiting for first -
// 1 -> reading the answer and waiting for second -
// 2 -> finished reading
uint8_t state = 0;

while (client.connected() || client.available()) {
    char c = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer

    if ((c == '-') && (state < 2))
        state++;
    if ((state == 1) && (c != '-'))
        readString += c;
}

client.stop(); //stop client

Serial.print(readString);
String val = "happy";

if(res == val){
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" happy");
}else{
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" sad");
}
```

Anyway, I really don't like using variable size variables in arduino, since you have very few memory (so why should you waste it?). My suggestion is to always use fixed-sized strings (aka char array). For instance:

```
// state =
// 0 -> waiting for first -
// 1 -> reading the answer and waiting for second -
// 2 -> finished reading
uint8_t state = 0;

char readString[MAX_SIZE+1];
uint8_t readStringIndex = 0;

while (client.connected() || client.available()) {
    char c = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer

    if ((c == '-') && (state < 2))
        state++;
    if ((state == 1) && (c != '-'))
    {
        readString[readStringIndex] = c;
        readStringIndex++;
    }
}
readString[readStringIndex] = '\0'; // string terminator

client.stop(); //stop client

Serial.print(readString);

if(strcmp(readString, "happy")){
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" happy");
}else{
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" sad");
}
```

**EDIT:**

The OP mentioned that the strings are not delimited anymore by two '-', but instead they are enclosed between '<' and '>'.

The code, consequently, should be modified in this way:

```
// state =
// 0 -> waiting for first -
// 1 -> reading the answer and waiting for second -
// 2 -> finished reading
uint8_t state = 0;

char readString[MAX_SIZE+1];
uint8_t readStringIndex = 0;

while (client.connected() || client.available()) {
    char c = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer

    switch (state)
    {
        case 0: // Waiting for first char
            if (c == '<')
                state = 1;
            break;
        case 1: // Reading the answer and waiting for second char
            if (c == '>')
                state = 2;
            else
            {
                readString[readStringIndex] = c;
                readStringIndex++;
            }
            break;
    }
}
readString[readStringIndex] = '\0'; // string terminator

client.stop(); //stop client

Serial.print(readString);

if(strcmp(readString, "happy")){
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" happy");
}else{
    Serial.print(readString);
    Serial.println(" sad");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, the code is working, however there are a couple of issues: the string contains '<' at the beginning and the arduino crashes (litterally) and after some time restart by it self from the setup(). I never heard of such behave, do you have idea what could cause this? thanks

Comment: @SkaFrenz are you using the first or second code? So the string based or the char array based? As for the '<', what is the complete string you are parsing? is there a < after the first -? Please note that if you are using a browser to view the server response, maybe the < is not shown (in this case look at the page source code - CTRL-U on chrome or some other shortcuts on other browsers)

Comment: Hi, I'm using the second (array). Sorry, I didn't mention this but I changed '-' with '<' and '>' (beginning and end of my string). I'm using the serial monitor to print out the values.

Comment: @SkaFrenz I modified the answer to deal with the new delimiters. Since the start and end delimiters are different you should differentiate the two bounds: it's easier using the classical switch-case approach used in finite state machines.

Comment: @SkaFrenz glad it worked ;) if the answer was correct, anyway, please mark it as solved (click the tick on the left of the answer)